# How i can run a script outside from standalone application made in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a standalone app in matlab. It gets a file name as an input and need to run this file.
The file is on the same path as the standalone app.

thx, 
Mike.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-a` option to compile additional files.

For instance, with this command you'll be able to call any .m file in your current directory from your standalone application:

```
mcc -m myscript.m -a *.m
```

Comment: Can i do it without compiling ? for example I can run files implicit like this: "!filename" but i can't find a way to give that command with incoming input. What i would like to do is:
T = FileNameInputFromUser (M file)
!T

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.... If you do like I said above, you can give any script name as an input and launch it from your stand alone application. If the script you want to launch did not exist at compile time, or if it has not been added with `-a`, you cannot execute it from your standalone application.

Comment: The problem is that new scripts are added, and i don't won't to compile each time the whole application.

Comment: You cannot do it without recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the [SYSTEM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/system.html) function.  You can pass it any variable as a string:

```
s = 'ls';  % use 'ls' for Mac/Unix, 'dir' for Windows
[status, result] = system(s);
```

Here `status` is the OS status code (0 means the program exited without error), and `result` is the output of the program:

```
>> status

status =

     0

>> result

result =



total 928
-rw-r--r--   1 stew  stew       0 Jul 24  2009 PROJECT_BASE
drwxr-xr-x  48 stew  stew    1632 Mar 17  2011 analysis
-rw-r--r--   1 stew  stew    1944 Oct  4  2010 diff1
drwxr-xr-x  29 stew  stew     986 Sep 24  2011 matlab
drwxr-xr-x  11 stew  stew     374 Aug  5  2009 matlab_old
-rw-r--r--   1 stew  stew   62525 Jul  6  2010 nms.mat
-rw-r--r--   1 stew  stew  111423 Jul  7  2010 nms1.mat
drwxr-xr-x  52 stew  stew    1768 Mar  2  2010 p60_analysis
drwxr-xr-x   4 stew  stew     136 Mar 26 23:08 sims
-rw-r--r--   1 stew  stew    2212 Jan 29  2010 startup.m
-rw-r--r--   1 stew  stew  264635 Jun 13 18:22 test.bundle
-rw-r--r--   1 stew  stew     128 Sep 24  2010 testlatt.m
-rw-r--r--   1 stew  stew    4618 Jun 15  2011 tt-conn-ERRSTATE.mat
-rw-r--r--   1 stew  stew    6221 Jun 13 17:50
update_2012_June_13.bundle
drwxr-xr-x   4 stew  stew     136 Jun 13 18:28 videos
```

NB: If the program is not on your executable path, you may need to specify its absolute path:

```
s = '/usr/bin/ls';
[status, result] = system(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I asked exactly a similar question and could not get an answear.

[Is it possible to execute compiled code both within and out of MATLAB environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566991/is-it-possible-to-execute-compiled-code-both-within-and-out-of-matlab-environmen)

I believe it is not possible as Mathworks doesn't want you to distribute a free Matlab interpreter. I wonder if one can compile two set of M files separately and run the second from the first as a workaround.